# Events Not Queueing

Tags: c#

I am trying to handle multiple button click events in such a way that the events will be executed one after the other using Queue(). Somehow no events are being queued when i print the Count and i can't figure out why. The code is as follows.

```
        private void callBtn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            if ((btn.Name == ("btn" + 0))
            {
                buttonQueue.Enqueue(btn);
                closeDoors();
            }
            else if ((btn.Name == ("btn" + 1))
            {
                buttonQueue.Enqueue(btn);
                closeDoors();
            }
            while(buttonQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                buttonQueue.Dequeue();
                listBox.Items.Add("Number: " + buttonQueue.Count);
            }
```

Comment: What you are trying to queue - buttons or `closeDoors` actions?

Comment: What's the point of enqueuing something if you dequeue it immediately?

Answer (score 2):

You are dequeuing just added item, thus next call to `Count` returns zero:

```
// add one item

while(buttonQueue.Count > 0) // Count is 1
{
    buttonQueue.Dequeue(); // remove one item
    listBox.Items.Add("Number: " + buttonQueue.Count); // Count is 0
}
```

Comment: I am queueing buttons that call a method to close doors on two seperate floors. I am a newby to this and still trying to get my head round things.

Comment: @user3034845 it's clear that you want to enqueue buttons when they are clicked, but when you want to remove buttons from queue?

Answer (score 1):

A subsequent UI thread call to `callBtn0_Click` cannot execute until an existing call completes.  Based on your code, only 1 item can be in the queue and you dequeue said item immediately after adding it.

I suggest you read about UI threads and the message pump